# Is there any option to delete user profile and user data on windows 10?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Is there any option to delete the user profile and user data (user installed apps and user created folders and files) in PowerShell?

I have played with Win32_Userprofile class, By deleting that we can only delete user folder in "c:\users" and registry keys.
I want to delete user created folders, apps and files in any drive on deleting the user.

Comment: There is no straight forward method other than going through the ACLs for the user and figure out what are various access levels. For AD user, you can try something like this - `(Get-ACL "AD:$((Get-ADUser Twon.of.An).distinguishedname)").access`

Comment: I have the admin access but what I really want is, Is there any way to delete user created data on disk that not lies in "c:\\users"

Comment: How would the system know what data the user created?

Comment: I second Ansgar. There is no trace in the system level Vijay. No exposure for the system to identify like that unless you are maintaining and internal tracker.

Comment: Thanks, @RanadipDutta. I Understand that.